# How to add titles from a list to a series of histograms?

Tags: r, histogram, graphing

Is it possibile to attach titles via an apply-family function to a series of histograms where the titles are picked from a list?

The code below creates three histograms. I want to give each a different name from a list (named "list"), in order. How do I do this?

```
data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
outcome <-data[,c(11,17,23)]
out <- apply(outcome, 2,as.data.frame) 
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
apply(outcome,2, hist, xlim=range(out,na.rm=TRUE), xlab="30 day death rate")
```

Comment: I have edited your question. If you feel I made a mistake, please don't hesitate to revert my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not only the columns but another argument that changes, you may use `mapply` to have a function from the `apply` family.

```
args <- list(xlim=range(data, na.rm=TRUE), xlab="30 day death rate")
titles <- list("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3")
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
mapply(hist, data, main=titles, MoreArgs=args)
```

If you wrap the `invisible` function around the last line you can avoid the console output.

[image]

**Note**: I think using loops here is far more straightforward.

Comment: I am trying to use the github data "outcome-of-care-measures.csv". But I am not reaching there the plot like you.

Comment: my plot uses random data. add a link to the data to make your example fully reproducible.

Comment: @MarkHeckmann  That's is near my original idea, using the apply-family instead of loops if possibile. But seems don't working in the specific case and/or with this data. What I obtain is this error     Error in hist.default(dots[[1L]][[4L]], main = dots[[2L]][[1L]], xlab = "30 day death rate",  : 
  invalid number of 'breaks'

Comment: Please make your example (in your question above) complete and reproducible. Right now we do not know why the code fails, and do not have the information to provide additional feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `facet_wrap` from `ggplot2` to get this done. `ggplot2` supports this kind of plots very painlessly:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

df = data.frame(values = rnorm(3000), ID = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 1000))
ggplot(df, aes(x = values)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ ID)
```

[image]

To change the text in the box above each facet, simply replace the text in the `ID` variable:

```
id_to_text_translator = c(A = 'Facet text for A',
                          B = 'Facet text for B',
                          C = 'Facet text for C')
df$ID = id_to_text_translator[df$ID]
```

I would recommend taking a close look at what happens in these two lines. Using vectorized subsetting to perform this kind of replacement has compact syntax and high performance. Replacing this code would require a `for` or `apply` loop combined with a set of `if` statements would make the code much longer and slower.

Another option is to directly influence the `levels` of `ID`, which is a `factor`:

```
levels(df$ID) = id_to_text_translator[levels(df$ID)]
```

This is a lot faster, especially on datasets with a lot of rows. In addition, it keeps `ID` a `factor`, while the previous solution makes `ID` a `character` vector.

The resulting plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = values)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ ID)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but if I want different, more articulate, name for each histogram? Or name picked from a list how I could do that?

Comment: + Inf for ggplot! It's really great. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/): For the "title" that is actually the [facets](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html) name, i would just modify my data accordingly.